# Is Hell, the Lake of Fire & the Bottomless Pit all the same place?

Tags: new-testament, hell, revelation

For what reason is there for a new prison of the damned if there already is one in Sheol?

Is it possible they all speak of the same place, just having multiple names for different points in scripture?

All the scriptures that use these words in the Authorized King James:

- [Hell](https://www.biblegateway.com/quicksearch/?search=Hell&version=AKJV&searchtype=phrase&resultspp=500)
- [Bottomless Pit](https://www.biblegateway.com/quicksearch/?search=Bottomless+pit&version=AKJV&searchtype=phrase&resultspp=500)
- [Lake of Fire:](https://www.biblegateway.com/quicksearch/?search=Lake+of+fire&version=AKJV&searchtype=phrase&resultspp=500)

From what I've seen most people believe that there is two places created for the wicked.

The first being Hell, located in Sheol which is across a gulf that separates it from what is referred to as Abraham's Bosom or Paradise. The wicked go to Hell and the righteous to Paradise. And that these are the holding places of both the wicked and righteous until the first and second resurrections of which some think may even happen at the same time rather than a 1000 years apart.

And the second place being the Lake of Fire which is where  "death and hell" (Rev 20:14) is cast after the 2nd resurrection along with the Devil and the rest of the damned. Is this Lake of Fire a new prison, a new place of torment?

We already know that in the current prison in Sheol, called Hell, that there is torments(Luke 16:24-25) and that it is able to hold innumerable multitudes of people.

So what reason is there for creating a new place for the wicked?

Comment: Which denomination are you asking for the belief of? Different denominations have very different beliefs regarding Hell, Sheol, and the Lake of Fire.

Comment: @www.gffg.info Unfortunately, that kind of question is not on-topic on this site. [We can't handle the truth.](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3527/32540)

Comment: @www.gffg.info says "I'm looking for scriptural based answers."  So perhaps the Hermeneutics site might have been more appropriate.  In any case, I've just posted an answer that tries to be Bible-based, not specific to any denomination's doctrines.